# Payment transaction failed -email items -variable

Tags: email, payment

The email message shows items in cart like this:

```
Items
Item name x 2 EUR 2
Item 2 name x 1 EUR 3
Item 3 name x 30 EUR 4
```

How to add the product sku there? Like:

```
Items
Item name (sku1) x 2 EUR 2
Item 2 name (sku2) x 1 EUR 3
Item 3 name (sku3) x 30 EUR 4
```

In email template it is done like this:
          
`<p>
    <b>Items</b><br />
    {{var items}}
</p>`
But how to edit the way the {{var items}} -part prints out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at sendPaymentFailedEmail() in  /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php which is call from /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

The only email variables are :

```
array(
    'reason' => $message,
    'checkoutType' => $checkoutType,
    'dateAndTime' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(),
    'customer' => $checkout->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $checkout->getCustomerLastname(),
    'customerEmail' => $checkout->getCustomerEmail(),
    'billingAddress' => $checkout->getBillingAddress(),
    'shippingAddress' => $checkout->getShippingAddress(),
    'shippingMethod' => Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippingMethod.'/title'),
    'paymentMethod' => Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentMethod.'/title'),
    'items' => nl2br($items),  **<-- display items in your template**
    'total' => $total
)
```

Since there are no observer trigger your only option would be to do a rewrite and modify this code below accordingly to include sku

```
foreach ($checkout->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    /* @var $_item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
    $items .= $_item->getProduct()->getName() . '  x '. $_item->getQty() . '  '
            . $checkout->getStoreCurrencyCode() . ' '
            . $_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice($_item->getQty()) . "\n";
}
```